# Delphi: Open a PDF (Sumatra, Foxit and Adobe) file programmatically at a named destination in the PDF

Tags: delphi, pdf, named

I'm the main developer of an open source project (http://nbcgib.uesc.br/lec/software/editores/tinn-r/en).

Now the user guide of the project is in PDF (make under LaTeX).

I'm trying to making a procedure to open the User guide programmatically at a named destination/section *in the PDF*.

As I do not know the default PDF viewer of the users, I'm developing a procedure to support the major: Sumatra, Foxit and Adobe.

The procedure is working fine for Sumatra, but not for Foxit and Adobe.

Below the code:

```
function GetAssociation(const DocFileName: string): string;
var
  FileClass: string;
  Reg: TRegistry;

begin
  Result:= '';
  Reg:= TRegistry.Create(KEY_EXECUTE);
  Reg.RootKey:= HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT;
  FileClass:= '';
  if Reg.OpenKeyReadOnly(ExtractFileExt(DocFileName)) then
  begin
    FileClass:= Reg.ReadString('');
    Reg.CloseKey;
  end;
  if FileClass <> '' then begin
    if Reg.OpenKeyReadOnly(FileClass +
                           '\Shell\Open\Command') then
    begin
      Result:= Reg.ReadString('');
      Reg.CloseKey;
    end;
  end;
  Reg.Free;
end;

procedure TfrmTinnMain.OpenUserGuidePDF(sWhere: string);
var
  sFile,
   sViewerDefault,
   sParameter: string;

begin
  sViewerDefault:= GetAssociation('.pdf');

  if pos('Sumatra',                     // Sumatra: OK
         sViewerDefault) > 0 then
    sParameter:= '-reuse-instance ' +
                 '-named-dest ' +
                 sWhere
  else if pos('Foxit',                  // Foxit: opens the file, but not at the named destination
              sViewerDefault) > 0 then
    sParameter:= '/A ' +
                 'page=100'
  else if pos('Adobe',                  // Adobe: opens the file, but not at the named destination
              sViewerDefault) > 0 then begin
    sWhere:= StringReplace(sWhere,
                           '"',
                           '',
                           [rfReplaceAll]);

    sParameter:= '/A ' +
                 '"' +
                 'nameddest=' +
                 sWhere +
                 '"';
  end
  else
    sParameter:= '';

  sFile:= sPathTinnR +
          '\doc\User guide.pdf';
  try
    // Open PDF viewer
    ShellExecute(0,
                 'open',
                 Pchar(sFile),
                 Pchar(sParameter),
                 nil,
                 sw_shownormal);

  except
    MessageDlg('PDF viewer is not accessible!',
               mtInformation,
               [mbOk],
               0);
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmTinnMain.menHelUserGuideClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  OpenUserGuidePDF('"Contents"');
end;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: In what way is it not "working fine"? What do you expect the program to do, and what happens instead? What have you learned from the debugger?

Comment: PDF is very poor choice for the online reference facility.

Comment: I want to open the User guide (Sumatra, Foxit and Adobe) at any specific named destination. For example: "Database", "Configuration", etc. The procedure is already working for Sumatra, but not for Foxit and Adobe Reader.

Comment: You already said that. What is the question though. What are you expecting to happen? What actually happens? In what way does the actual behaviour fail to meet your expectation? How can we reproduce your test environment given that we do not want to install your software.

Comment: It is not necessary to install my software! See new comments in the procedure **OpenUserGuidePDF**

Comment: Where is the PDF file? Can't you make an SSCCE? What I find frustrating here is that the question has nothing at all to do with Delphi. It is 100% an issue relating to passing command line parameters to certain PDF viewers. Why don't you ask a question along the lines of, *I am passing the following arguments to Acrobat.exe with the intention of opening the document at a specific location. The document opens, but not at the desired location. What parameters do I need to pass to meet my goal?* If you want to make progress you will need to learn how to simplify a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to thanks all observations and suggestions!

I found it more practical to distribute (jointly with Tinn-R) the portable version of [SumatraPDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/download-free-pdf-viewer.html).
If Sumatra is the system default it will be used. Otherwise, the portable version will be used.

Below the computational solution:

```
procedure TfrmTinnMain.OpenUserGuidePDF(sWhere: string);
var
  sFile,
   sViewerDefault,
   sPathSumatra,
   sParameter: string;

begin
  sFile:= sPathTinnR +
          '\doc\User guide.pdf';

  sParameter:= '-reuse-instance ' +
               '-named-dest ' +
               sWhere;
  try
    sViewerDefault:= GetAssociation('.pdf');

    if pos('Sumatra',
           sViewerDefault) > 0 then
      // Open default PDF viewer
      ShellExecute(0,
                   'open',
                   Pchar(sFile),
                   Pchar(sParameter),
                   nil,
                   sw_shownormal)
    else begin
      sPathSumatra:= sPathTinnR +
                     '\sumatra\SumatraPDF.exe';

      // Open SumatraPDF viewer
      OpenCmdLine(sPathSumatra +
                  ' "' +
                  sFile +
                  '"' +
                  sParameter,
                  sw_shownormal);
    end;
  except
    MessageDlg('PDF viewer is not accessible!',
               mtInformation,
               [mbOk],
               0);
  end;
end;
```

The call:

```
procedure TfrmTinnMain.menHelUserGuideClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  OpenUserGuidePDF('"Contents"');
end;
```

Necessary functions and procedures:

```
{ Execute a complete shell command line without waiting. }
function OpenCmdLine(const CmdLine: string;
                     wWindowState: Word): Boolean;
var
  sUInfo: TStartupInfo;
  pInfo : TProcessInformation;

begin
  { Enclose filename in quotes to take care of long filenames with spaces. }
  FillChar(sUInfo,
           SizeOf(sUInfo),
           #0);
  with SUInfo do
  begin
    cb         := SizeOf(sUInfo);
    dwFlags    := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    wShowWindow:= wWindowState;
  end;
  Result:= CreateProcess(nil,
                         PChar(CmdLine),
                         nil,
                         nil,
                         False,
                         CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE or
                         NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
                         nil,
                         nil {PChar(ExtractFilePath(sFileName))},
                         sUInfo,
                         pInfo);
end;

function GetAssociation(const DocFileName: string): string;
var
  FileClass: string;
  Reg: TRegistry;

begin
  Result:= '';
  Reg:= TRegistry.Create(KEY_EXECUTE);
  Reg.RootKey:= HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT;
  FileClass:= '';
  if Reg.OpenKeyReadOnly(ExtractFileExt(DocFileName)) then
  begin
    FileClass:= Reg.ReadString('');
    Reg.CloseKey;
  end;
  if FileClass <> '' then begin
    if Reg.OpenKeyReadOnly(FileClass +
                           '\Shell\Open\Command') then
    begin
      Result:= Reg.ReadString('');
      Reg.CloseKey;
    end;
  end;
  Reg.Free;
end;
```

Any suggestion will be welcome!

All the best,

J.C.Faria

Comment: There are plenty of problems with your code. For a start, the second parameter to CreateProcess must be writeable. Your code will fail with a literal in a Unicode build. Use UniqueString to make that param modifiable. You need to use try/finally to protect objects. The TRegistry instance for example. Your call to CreateProcess leaks the handles returned in the process info parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Let Windows decide what the default viewer for that file type is:

```
ShellExecute(0, 'open', Filename, nil, nil, SW_SHOW);
```

Comment: -1 User wants to navigate to a specific location in the document

Comment: I know this general call to ShellExecute. But, I want be more specific: I want to open the User guide (Sumatra, **Foxit** and **Adobe**) at any specific named destination. For example: "Database", "Configuration", etc. The procedure is already working for Sumatra, but not for Foxit and Adobe Reader.